# how do you create a new PSBT transaction in bitcoinjs-lib?

Tags: javascript, typescript, bitcoin

This is my code

```js
import * as bitcoin from 'bitcoinjs-lib'
const NETWORK = bitcoin.networks.regtest;
const psbt = new bitcoin.Psbt({ network: NETWORK });

function p2shAddress(node: bitcoin.ECPairInterface): string {
  const ecpair = bitcoin.ECPair.fromPublicKey(node.publicKey, { network: NETWORK });
  const p2wpkh = bitcoin.payments.p2wpkh({ pubkey: ecpair.publicKey, network: NETWORK });
  const p2sh = bitcoin.payments.p2sh({ redeem: p2wpkh });
  return p2sh.address as string;
}

const tx = '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';
// this is the raw-tx I sent to 2NFJUYmdpAPRoo6qqUZem7rmBq2QSSPKBPu.
// did I understand it wrong, and this is not the supposed to be nonWitnessUtxo?

psbt.addInput({
  hash: '25ba0c45cadf92ded94432101d286975dcdb865df44b68da597910ea783cff74',
  index: 0,
  nonWitnessUtxo: Buffer.from(tx, 'hex'),
});
psbt.addOutput({
  address: '2MuhtGHkdxiL4BjFAAaYjq8Q2mwnCoYSebt',
  value: 4000,
});
const signer = bitcoin.ECPair.fromPrivateKey(Buffer.from('64e897b5fac936a30a7a73e1c2892697c91b0705a8d061ea28e59f41d2876e0d', 'hex'), { network: NETWORK });
console.log({ address: p2shAddress(signer) });
// { address: '2NFJUYmdpAPRoo6qqUZem7rmBq2QSSPKBPu' }
psbt.signInput(0, signer);
psbt.validateSignaturesOfInput(0, signer.publicKey);
```

but I'm getting error: `Can not sign for this input with the key 02c4ac...`

I've made sure that when I decode the tx using `bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction $TX` 
the first vout (index 0), has the address as shown by p2shAddress(signer), which is `2NFJUYmdpAPRoo6qqUZem7rmBq2QSSPKBPu`.

can someone point out where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this utxo input is a `p2sh` address, so you need a `redeemScript` field for the input:

```
const node = signer;
const ecpair = bitcoin.ECPair.fromPublicKey(node.publicKey, { network: NETWORK });
const p2wpkh = bitcoin.payments.p2wpkh({ pubkey: ecpair.publicKey, network: NETWORK });

psbt.addInput({
  hash: '25ba0c45cadf92ded94432101d286975dcdb865df44b68da597910ea783cff74',
  index: 0,
  nonWitnessUtxo: Buffer.from(tx, 'hex'),
  redeemScript: p2wpkh.output
});
```

Hope it helps!